# How to properly package an Ubuntu Touch application with Qt Creator (Ubuntu SDK)

Tags: application-development, package-management, ubuntu-touch, qt-creator, ubuntu-sdk

In the new Ubuntu SDK there is an option to "Create application package" in "Build/Ubuntu Touch". Is there any tutoriel to explain how it works? It seems that it creats a "debian" folder with many things in it like the "control" and other basic files. The name of the maintainer seems to be taken direcly from the name of the user and its email address is created with the first word. How can I change all of this?

If I change in every files I can find in "debian", it doesn't work when I hit the "Create application package" again. Also since I am French and that my firstname has a "é", it creats an error in Ubuntu Software Center, which is very infortunate.

Where can I find some doc about this option in Ubuntu SDK? There is a lot for packaging doc for Ubuntu but none for Ubuntu Touch.

Thank you and sorry to ask something again but I am new in this kind of things and the tuto on the Ubuntu website [(here)](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/tutorials/getting-started/currency-converter-phone-app/) stops before the packaging. It might be a good thing to go from the begining to the end on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The packaging of Ubuntu Touch application is in a transitional period right now. The emphasis is more on the new Click packaging format and less on the good old .deb format. In the present Ubuntu SDK relase both are supported.

For the .deb packaging the QtCreator relies on two environment vairables, the DEBEMAIL and the DEBFULLNAME. You can set those variables in the .bashrc file in the home folder. The .deb packaging feature in the QTCreator works fine and it is good for playing around, but the development effort is going on the new Click packaging.

Comment: Thank for your answer but it doesn't resolve my problem, how and where can I can information in debian/control when using  Qt Creator ? Because every time I change something in debian/control and then build the paquage, no changes are taken into account.